# Filtering or of multiple between in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
l = [
     (100, 230),
     (10, 12),
     (7,1320),
     ...
    ]
```

I want to generate a query in SQLAlchemy that the `value` field of my table are between `100 , 230` or `10, 12`or `7, 1320` and so on.

my table looks like this:

```
id  | value
----|------
1   | 120
2   | 2
3   | 9
4   | 1245
5   | 4512
```

in this case I want these ids: `1,3,4`.
I did something like this but I cant do the `or` part so it just filter the rows that matches all criteria

```
 q = session.query(Table.value)
 for f in l:
     q = q.filter((Table.value.between(f[0], f[1])))
```

I'm using **Python3.6**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy provides `or_` to combine filter clauses:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
...
q = session.query(Table.id)
q = q.filter(or_(Table.value.between(100, 230), Table.value.between(10, 12)))
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_), `or_` actually receives variable number of clauses, so you can use list comprehension + unpacking technique to pass your filter boundaries to it as following:

```
q = q.filter(or_(*[Table.value.between(left, right) for left, right in l]))
```

The `*` is the unpack operator, it will unpack the arguments out of a list or tuple and pass them as separate positional arguments to a function call.

Comment: You should explain your use of `*` to unpack your list comprehension, it may seem like an opaque solution for users who haven't come across it before. For example, show the long version, `q.filter(or_(Table.value.between(100, 230), Table.value.between(10, 12)))` as the answer to the question, then add the list comprehension + unpacking technique as a nice way to write terse but equally readable code

Comment: You are right, I should explain more. Edited and thanks for the advice. @daveruinseverything.

Comment: @CtheSky thankyou for your answer. the extra information was unnecessary, but thanks. :)